in python, why does the input variable make the loop not run but making it a function allows both the input and the loop to run?
I am not too sure how to phrase the title.
operation = ("Addition", "Subtraction", "Multiplication", "Division")

def choose():
    input("Choose an operation: ").casefold().strip()

def operations():
    for op in operation:
        index = operation.index(op) + 1
        print(index, ".", op)

operations()
choose()

When I run the above, the output is the list of names, and under it is the question. But if I turn the input prompt into a variable (see below), only the question runs and the list is basically ignored.
operation = ("Addition", "Subtraction", "Multiplication", "Division")
choose = input("Choose an operation: ").casefold().strip()

def operations():
    for op in operation:
        index = operation.index(op) + 1
        print(index, ".", op)

operations()
choose

What is the reason?
if I put:
operations()
input("Choose an operation: ").casefold().strip()

Then that also runs both the list and the question. But I need the return value for later use so this won't be beneficial.
I don't understand why a function works but the variable blocks the loop?

"the list is basically ignored" - What do you mean by that? Once you fill in the prompt, then the loop runs. That's not what you want of course, but it's not the behaviour you're describing. Did you not try filling in the prompt? Please be explicit: show what input you're giving the script and what output it gives you. For reference see [mre].

choose on its own does nothing in a script. What were you expecting it to do?

In your second example, the call to input() is not contained inside a function, therefore it is executed right away.

"But i need the return value for later use" - Then why aren't you capturing it? choice = input("Choose an operation: ")...

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] if you want tips.

From your description, it sounds like you haven't tried to input anything. In your second example, the list would display after input. That's likely not what you want, but if you tried that and changed your question to reflect that test, the question would make more sense.


But if i turn the input prompt into a variable

You're not turning the input prompt into a variable, you're assigning the result of the prompt to that variable, so it is executed in that point.
After that, the script calls the operations() function, and shows the variable.
The first example is the correct one to do what you want to do (and sure, there may be more solutions).
In the second one the prompt not block the loop, it happens after prompt.
